# Dialog Preferences from my PreferenceActivity aren't being saved

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I have a bunch of EditTextPreferences and a TimePickerPrefernce(that I created) along with one CheckBoxPreference and none of the EditTextPreference or TimePickerPreference get saved, but the CheckBox does. I thought it might have been because of the bare minimum I have in my PreferenceActivity subclass, but seeing as how the checkbox gets saved I'm not sure if that is.

I've searched all over and everything seems to say that preferences should be automatically saved, and I can't find out any reason why they wouldn't be.

Here is my preference xml file:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_general_header" >
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="15"
        android:summary="@string/settings_time_to_sleep"
        android:title="@string/settings_time_to_sleep_title" 
        android:numeric="integer" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="90"
        android:summary="@string/settings_sleep_cycle_time_summary"
        android:title="@string/settings_sleep_cycle_minutes" 
        android:numeric="integer" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="5"
        android:summary="@string/how_many_results"
        android:title="@string/settings_results_to_show_title" 
        android:numeric="integer" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/wakeupat_settings_header" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="@string/save_wakeupat_time"
        android:title="@string/save_wakeupat_time" android:defaultValue="false"/>

    <TimePickerPreference
        android:dependency="@string/save_wakeupat_time"
        android:title="@string/wakeupat_preferred_time" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

and here is my PreferenceActivity subclass:

```
package com.krej.timeforbed;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to define `android:key` in all your controls (*EditTextPreference* and *TimePickerPreference*) to let the framework save values automatically.

And since you have defined it in *CheckBoxPreference* that's why its saving it automatically.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Everything seems to be working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, that PreferenceActivity seemed to read preferences correcly, but I didn't see changes in myPreferences after user had changed some attributes. All you need before you access preferences after they are updated by PreferencesActivity is to recreate myPreferences like this:

```
myPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

... it seems, that two instances of preferences are not synchronized (may be because it is cached somehow). Changes in one instance doesn't appear in another although they are both of the same name (or they are both default shared prefereneces).